# Как скачать приложение из Google Play программно?

Tags: android

Как можно скачать приложение из Google Play к себе на телефон в виде APK? Я пробую [этим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931590/download-app-from-google-play-programatically/16944454#16944454) способом, но у меня не выходит, получаю ошибку `NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>`. Видимо, ошибка на стороне библиотеки.

Comment: Простого способа нет.

Comment: так я не против сложного способа

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можете установить lucky patcher, его нет в google play, так что придется качать со сторонних сайтов, а значит устанавливаете вы его на свой страх и риск (лично у меня проблем с ним не возникало).
Устанавливаем приложение с которого нужно сделать .apk файл. Запускаем lucky patcher, программа ищет приложения на смартфоне, после чего в списке находим нужное приложение, нажимаем на его, выбираем Инструменты, создать резервную копию, после чего вам выведет путь где будет лежать нужный вам файл (у меня sdcard/Android/data/com.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.LOCK/files/LuckyPatcher/ и тут файл).
Еще вместо резервной копии можно нажать Поделиться приложением, тогда можно закинуть его на dropbox, либо через ES6 в нужную папку.
Возможно здесь много написано, но делается все довольно быстро, сам много раз так делал и перекидывал игры другим. Может быть не самое лучшее решение, но как вариант можете попробовать.